# How to select element in Protractor by html attribute when value contains

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Struggling with how to select an element that doesn't have a standard unique id or class.  How would I select this input element with Protractor?

Note: I cannot use the class `ComboBoxInput_Default` class, as this drop down box is used on several other page elements. There also isn't any easily identifiable parent element for at least 10+ DOM levels.

```
<div style="display:inline; white-space: nowrap;" id="ctl00_ctl31_g_b56afa08_7869_450c_8871_f6759a89d9b1_ctl00_WPQ3txtFields_ddPositioList_10_Solution_MultiComboSelection" class="ComboBox_Default">
  <input type="text" style="width: 133px; height: 15px;" delimiter=";" class="ComboBoxInput_Default" value="-select-" name="ctl00$ctl31$g_b56afa08_7869_450c_8871_f6759a89d9b1$ctl00$WPQ3txtFields_ddPositioList_10_Solution_MultiComboSelection_Input" id="ctl00_ctl31_g_b56afa08_7869_450c_8871_f6759a89d9b1_ctl00_WPQ3txtFields_ddPositioList_10_Solution_MultiComboSelection_Input" autocomplete="off">    
<div>
```

The only identifying markup that makes each of these inputs different is appended to the end of the generated id, `Solution_MultiComboSelection_Input`.

If I had to get this element with jquery, I would use the (not preferrable) contains `$( "input[name*='Solution_MultiComboSelection_Input']" )`.  Is there some comparable way to locate elements in this way with Protractor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, use the "contains" or "ends-with" CSS selector:

```
element(by.css("input[id*=Solution_MultiComboSelection_Input]"));
element(by.css("input[id$=Solution_MultiComboSelection_Input]"));
```

Comment: Ha! Nice Alecxe... didn't know we could do that. #helpful

Comment: Ah, great and thank you!  I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only element with ComboBoxInput_Default as the class, then you could select it using 
element(by.css('.ComboBoxInput_Default'))

[This page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/basic/elements_spec.js) has a lot of examples for selectors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a friendly reminder to make sure your answers can stand on their own, and don't rely on a external link to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know for sure without seeing the rest of the page but I'd try...

```
$('input[value="-select-"].ComboBoxInput_Default);
```

or maybe

```
$('div.ComboBoxInput_Default input.ComboBoxInput_Default);
```

That said, the best solution is to have an identifier added to the code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Brine!  Sorry, but I cannot select by the css class `ComboBoxInput_Default`, as the same class is used for 5 other inputs on the page.

Comment: Ahhh yeah, that's a tough one :) I like Alecxe's answer... hope that works for you!